# How to fix Add-AzureADGroupMember error in Azure AD

Tags: azure-powershell

I'm a bit baffled as to why I'm receiving the error shown below. I've followed the official documentation for the cmdlet which doesn't have much  and cannot figure out why I'm receiving this error. I'm feeding the correct ObjectID for the group and RefObjectID for the user.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/vt1Kv.png

Comment: Any question let me know, or if it is helpful, please mark it as the answer(on the left of my reply, there is an option to mark).

Comment: Any update this issue?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may be related to your group , if your group is e.g. Mail-enabled security groups, you could not update it directly in Azure AD, they are managed either from on-premises or from Exchange Online.

The command `Add-AzureADGroupMember` essentially calls the Azure AD Graph API, you could refer to this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869247/graph-api-add-member-on-mail-enabled-group-unable-to-update-the-specified-prope).

> Mail-enabled security groups cannot currently be updated directly in Azure AD, they are managed either from on-premises (if you're syncing from an on-premises directory with Azure AD Connect), or from Exchange Online.